# How to bind the event of clicking the back button in a browser to a specific function (for all the browsers)?

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, dom-events

I have got two scenarios:

1. user accesses to page A; then click on a link to go to page B; click back button to go back to page A;
2. user accesses to page A; then click on a link to go to page B; click on another link to go to page A;

I need a particular behavior to happen when the user is back to page A clicking the back button. Is that any way to do that in all the browsers. If I bind a function to "**beforeunload**" event in page B, the event is triggered in whatever way I am leaving the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had almost the exact same question I think this is what you need https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history